# CSS: aligning overlays

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a responsive design logo, using 2 strings, both slightly transparent. The strings are in different sizes, with the second on top of the first.

I've nearly got what I want ([try](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_color) the HTML below) however I would like the right hand edge of the 2 strings to align - The Div extends to the width of the browser and the overlap changes with the width of the display.

Because I want to give the browser some choices over how it's rendered I would rather not use measurements in pixels.

If it is at all relevant - I plan to add additional elements either side of the Div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.outerText {
    position: relative;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 800%;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing: -0.1em;
    color: red;
    opacity: 0.2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.innerText {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 600%;
    text-align:right;
    letter-spacing: -0.1em;
    float: right;
    color: blue;
    opacity: 0.2;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
and the result is....<br />
<div style="position:relative">
    <span class="outerText">OuterTxt</span>
    <span class="innerText">InnerTxt</span>
</div>
<hr />
...nearly right - but the rt edges are not (necessarily) aligned
</body>
</html>
```

Update: [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6QZtk/)

Comment: Create a jsfiddle so we can play with your code.

Comment: What do you mean by the right hand edge?

Comment: `postition: absolute;` has a typo.

Comment: @Explosion Pills: the right hand edge of the boxes defined by the 2 spans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a typo in your CSS ('postition' instead of 'position'), which was probably confusing things. Also, I think you want to remove the "float: right" once that typo is fixed.

This seems to be what (I think) you wanted:

```
div { /* make the selector more specific */
    height: 150px; /* or whatever's suitable */
}
.outerText {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.innerText {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 7px; /* adjust as desired to compensate for smaller font size */
    right: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nNMwb/2/

Comment: I don't think that's what I want - the baseline for the two texts doesn't match up, tand the unstyled text appears above the logo.

Comment: Can you make it look how you want now that the obvious problems are fixed? Without a picture it's hard for us to know what you want it to look like. You'll have to tweak the vertical position of one element yourself since they're different font sizes.

Comment: Thanks Blazemonger - it certainly looks as if this is doing what I want - just need to test it out now.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Viewport Sized Typography](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

Experiment with the `vw` unit, I've found that in your example `28.5vw` gives what seems to be the desired result.

```css
.outerText {
    position: relative;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 28.5vw;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing: -0.1em;
    color: red;
    opacity: 0.2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.innerText {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 28.5vw;
    text-align:right;
    letter-spacing: -0.1em;
    float: right;
    color: blue;
    opacity: 0.2;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/eYRSX/)

Comment: Nice - I didn't know about this type of sizing (as you may have gathered, CSS is not one of my strengths). Only downside is that it's not going to be supported by a large chunk of my user base :( http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Answer (score 0):

Embedding the Div in a table cell appears to give me the result I'm looking for - the inner and outer texts are both aligned on the right margin, share the same baseline and don't move relative to each other as the page is resized:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.outerText {
    postition: relative;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 800%;
    text-align: right;
        letter-spacing: -0.1em;
    color: red;
    opacity: 0.2;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.innerText {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 600%;
    text-align:right;
        letter-spacing: -0.1em;
    float: right;
    color: blue;
    opacity: 0.2;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
and the result is....<br />
<table>
<tr>
<td>left</td>
<td>
<div style="position:relative">
    <span class="outerText">OuterTxt</span>
    <span class="innerText">InnerTxt</span>
</div>
</td>
<td>right</td>
</tr>
</table>
<hr />
...yeah!
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No! No table-based layouts! Bad developer!

Comment: Yes - I know its messy - just rather verbose to add as a comment (I've not accepted this as my answer!)